# How can I create a common library for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, shared-libraries

my question is easy, I think. In my solution, I used to create different projects, for example, one for data logic (layer), business logic, etc.

Now, I have to create a library not only for my projects but also an SDK for third parties. I'm not sure if I create a PCL library, my third parties can use it in shared projects. In this library, I have to call `HttpClient` and I should use `Refit` and `Polly`.

I read on [Xamarin Help](https://xamarinhelp.com/portable-class-library-pcl-vs-shared-projects/) that Portable Class are obsolete. Really?

Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCL were superseded by SCL (.Net Standard) projects.
You can upgrade your existing projects, as described [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/)

For the new projects, just use .Net Standard